# How to write code and view results at the same time?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to create a rmarkdown document for monthly reports.  The issue I have is writing code and trying to visualize what the result would look like in the final document. I can generate and view maps in RStudio but this doesn't show me how they are positioned relative to text and other features within the output document (PDF, HTML etc)

Is there software that exists that allows you to write code in one window and view the product in another as code is developed? At the moment I am knitting the code and viewing the results in a trial and error process. It would be nice to see what the results look like in the document without having to rerun my file each time I change a piece of code and open the output document.

Kind regards,

Simon

Comment: Some of the tools built on top of RMarkdown like bookdown and blogdown have a preview feature (implemented using Rstudio addins) that automatically updates the output every time you save. HTML only, I think, and bookdown and blogdown both require extra setup that you don't necessarily want.

Comment: Thanks that helped quite a bit with my search. I see there are a couple of options out there.  The two options which look promising for what I want are EditR and the Ultimate Infinite Moon Reader. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you click the green arrow in the top right of your block of code, it will just run that block of code and won't create a full output file. It will also tell you where an error is if any.